# can't strcat_s multiple characters to string pointer

Tags: c

I'm trying to concatenate multiple strings to a string pointer to which I've allocated memory. Here's an example:

```
char *finalNumString = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
finalNumString[0] = '\0';
strcat_s(finalNumString, 10, "abcabcabc");
printf("added %d chars to finalNumString\n", 10);
strcat_s(finalNumString, 10, "abcabcabc");
printf("added %d chars to finalNumString\n", 10);
strcat_s(finalNumString, 10, "abcabcabc");
printf("added %d chars to finalNumString\n", 10);
```

After the first strcat_s command I get the error 'Debug assertion failed: L buffer is too small.' But I have malloc'd the memory! Why does this not work?

Comment: second argument is `numberOfElements. Size of the destination string buffer.`, make it `1024`.

Comment: OT: `sizeof(char)` is one by definition. Just drop it ... - or use `... = malloc(sizeof *finalNumString * 1024);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **[msdn page of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx)** `strcat_s()` function, it's definition is:

```
errno_t strcat_s(
   char *strDestination,
   size_t numberOfElements,
   const char *strSource 
);
```

here, `numberOfElements` refers to *Size of the destination string buffer*. So you need to send in `1024`(which is size of the destination string) as your second argument instead of `10` each time you use the `strcat_s()` function this way:

```
strcat_s(finalNumString, 1024, "abcabcabc");
```